# UISearchController with loading indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, loading, uisearchcontroller

I implemented `UISearchController` and I'm getting the data from a js callback but when I tape in the `searchbar` it takes some time to put the data so I wanted to know how to implement a loading `indicator` into the table view result of `UISearchController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start searching at that time you can create an activity indicator and add it as the `subview` of `UISearchBar` using `addSubView` method.

```
  UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

//set your frame for activity indicator

[searchBar addSubview: spinner];

[spinner startAnimating];
```

When you finish the search remove it from the search bar using `removeFromSuperView` method.

Comment: Thanks that what I was looking for ;)

Comment: glad.. i could help..:)

Answer (score 12):

Wrote this extension in Swift 3, which seems to work pretty well.

```
extension UISearchBar {

    private var textField: UITextField? {
        return subviews.first?.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UITextField }.first
    }

    private var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? {
        return textField?.leftView?.subviews.flatMap{ $0 as? UIActivityIndicatorView }.first
    }

    var isLoading: Bool {
        get {
            return activityIndicator != nil
        } set {
            if newValue {
                if activityIndicator == nil {
                    let newActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
                    newActivityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
                    newActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
                    newActivityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    textField?.leftView?.addSubview(newActivityIndicator)
                    let leftViewSize = textField?.leftView?.frame.size ?? CGSize.zero
                    newActivityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: leftViewSize.width/2, y: leftViewSize.height/2)
                }
            } else {
                activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Loading indicator on search results controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Y4D.png)

Comment: Nice one Ninja!

Answer (score 4):

Updated solution for iOS 13:

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var textField: UITextField? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return searchTextField
        } else {
           if let textField = value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
                return textField
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    private var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? {
        return textField?.leftView?.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UIActivityIndicatorView }.first
    }

    var isLoading: Bool {
        get {
            return activityIndicator != nil
        } set {
            if newValue {
                if activityIndicator == nil {
                    let newActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
                    newActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
                    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                        newActivityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGroupedBackground
                    } else {
                        newActivityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
                    }
                    newActivityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
                    textField?.leftView?.addSubview(newActivityIndicator)
                    let leftViewSize = textField?.leftView?.frame.size ?? CGSize.zero
                    newActivityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: leftViewSize.width/2, y: leftViewSize.height/2)
                }
            } else {
                activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. May be its helpfull to you

SearchBarWithloading.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchBarWithloading : UISearchBar

     - (void)startActivity;  // increments startCount and shows activity indicator
     - (void)finishActivity; // decrements startCount and hides activity indicator if 0

@end
```

SearchBarWithloading.m

```
import "SearchBarWithloading.h"

@interface SearchBarWithloading()

 @property(nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
 @property(nonatomic) int startCount;

@end


@implementation SearchBarWithloading

 - (void)layoutSubviews {
     UITextField *searchField = nil;

for(UIView* view in self.subviews){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        searchField= (UITextField *)view;
        break;
    }
}

if(searchField) {
    if (!self.activityIndicatorView) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *taiv = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        taiv.center = CGPointMake(searchField.leftView.bounds.origin.x + searchField.leftView.bounds.size.width/2,
                                  searchField.leftView.bounds.origin.y + searchField.leftView.bounds.size.height/2);
        taiv.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
        taiv.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.activityIndicatorView = taiv;
        [taiv release];
        _startCount = 0;

        [searchField.leftView addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    }
}

[super layoutSubviews];
}

 - (void)startActivity  {
   self.startCount = self.startCount + 1;
 }

  - (void)finishActivity {
     self.startCount = self.startCount - 1;
  }

  - (void)setStartCount:(int)startCount {
       _startCount = startCount;
      if (_startCount > 0)
         [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
      else {
          [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
      } 
 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution for iOS 13 and above:

```swift
extension UISearchController {
    
    private static let defaultLeftView: UIView = {
        UISearchTextField().leftView ?? UIView()
    }()
    
    private static let leftViewSize: CGSize = {
        UISearchTextField().leftView?.frame.size ?? .zero
    }()
    
    private static let loadingLeftView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: leftViewSize))
        
        let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)
        activityIndicatorView.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        
        view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        
        activityIndicatorView.center = CGPoint(x: leftViewSize.width / 2, y: leftViewSize.height / 2)
        
        return view
    }()
    
    func startLoading() {
        searchBar.searchTextField.leftView = Self.loadingLeftView
    }
    
    func stopLoading() {
        searchBar.searchTextField.leftView = Self.defaultLeftView
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).